# Чат для android

Tags: android

Хотел бы написать простейший чат для android, чтобы попрактиковаться. В моем понимании принцип чата такой: Есть БД, где регистрируются пользователи. Один пользователь выбирает второго (которому хочет отправить сообщение) и пишет сообщение. Оно отправляется на сервер, сервер проверяет второй пользователь онлайн или нет. Если онлайн, то пересылает ему сообщение, иначе хранит на сервере, пока не войдет пользователь.

Подскажите пожалуйста с чего начать, на чем писать серверную часть, алгоритм работы чата примерно правильный?

Comment: вы бы начинали практиковаться с Hello World какого-нибудь, раз представления не имеете ни о серверной части ни о клиентской :)

Comment: Ну обычные проги на андроид могу писать же, просто особо клиент-серверными не занимался. Вот решил попробовать что-то типа чата. Я знаю как работает сервер и клиент. Но на примере чата спрашивал более подробнее какой алгоритм будет.

Answer (score 1):

Можете написать серверную часть на фреймворке `Play`. Он очень простой и писать придется на Java. Также для чата вам нужно познакомится с сокетами. Для работы на андроиде есть Okhttp3. Там встроена поддержка сокетов. Вам только нужно будет сделать небольшие настройки. Стороне сервера можно вот эту либу использовать: [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться

Comment: @Колхозник присоединяюсь к совету pavel163. сам использую эту либу как на сервере, так и на клиентах. там и вариант применения wss работоспособный. правда есть недоработка при передачи больших бинарных файлов(я для себя поправил :)  ), в остальном стабильная либа.